# Show thread label in Debug navigator or other tools

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading

In my project a have a lot of background threads. I want to check if every thread works without crashes and disappear when needed. Because my program use 26% CPU. So i labeled every background thread:

```
let myQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQ", qos: .background, target: nil)

myQueue.async {
     someFunc()
}
```

But in Xcode Debug navigator i see unnamed threads:

[image]

**EDIT**

Hm, i found a way:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                Thread.current.name = "my thread"
                somefunc()
            }
```

But why then we need label in `DispatchQueue` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, i found a way:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                Thread.current.name = "my thread"
                somefunc()
            }
```

But why then we need label in DispatchQueue ?